# Substract years from a date

Tags: date, sas

I was wondering if someone could help me:
I have a date formatted as ddmmyyP10. From this date I want to substract a certain number of years (yrs). The date is the same for each observation, only yrs changes.

Example for my goal: date = 01.05.2018, yrs=3 -> resulting in 05.2015 (after formatting accordingly)

I have checked for yrdif, datdif and intnx but none of them seems to fit my data.

My (likely naive) first idea was to perform a simple substraction as I understood that sas stores dates internally as sas dates.
When I did

newdate=date-yrs;
format newdate monyy7.;

it showed for each observation May2018, so basically nothing happened.
Thanks in advance for your help!
Best wishes

Comment: Show the code using INTNX() function that you tried.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [INTNX()](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/8.11/lefunctionsref/p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm) function and proper formatting.

```
data have;
input date :ddmmyy10.;
format date ddmmyy10.;
datalines;
01.05.2018
;

data want;
set have;
newdate = intnx('Year', date, -3, 's');
format newdate mmyyp8.;
run;
```

```
newdate
05.2015
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! However in my case, the years to be substracted varies by observation. So instead of using a fix integer (such as the 3), I would actually like to use the variable itself, if this is possble:

Comment: Then just change the `-3` by your variable `yrs` like `intnx('Year', date, -yrs, 's');`